# Linux kernel for Khadas not supporting touchscreen (missing drivers?)

Tags: kernel, usb, touch-screen

I'm trying to get a touchscreen display to work on Khadas VIM3L. The touchscreen is USB. As soon as I plug it in both the USBs of the SBC stop working (no matter what device I plug in). This is `dmesg`:

```
[ 8384.786265] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
[ 8384.907490] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0416, idProduct=c168, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 8384.907507] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8384.907512] usb 1-1.1: Product: MTouch
[ 8384.907516] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: TSTP
[ 8384.907520] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: CMTP_1.0
[ 8395.322240] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.2.auto: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 8395.322254] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.2.auto: USBSTS:
[ 8395.346452] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.2.auto: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 8395.348739] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.2.auto: HC died; cleaning up
[ 8395.354199] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 8395.354932] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 8395.356118] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

I have tried 4.9 and mainline kernels, tried different OS but the result remained the same.

This is `dmesg` on my workstation where that touchscreen actually works (different architecture of course):

```
[ 1855.744065] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1855.897352] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0416, idProduct=c168, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 1855.897367] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1855.897373] usb 1-2: Product: MTouch
[ 1855.897377] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: TSTP
[ 1855.897381] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: CMTP_1.0
[ 1855.900892] input: TSTP MTouch as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:0416:C168.0006/input/input31
[ 1855.964524] hid-generic 0003:0416:C168.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [TSTP MTouch] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[ 1855.967057] input: TSTP MTouch as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:0416:C168.0007/input/input32
[ 1855.967237] hid-generic 0003:0416:C168.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [TSTP MTouch] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[ 1856.060779] input: TSTP MTouch as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:0416:C168.0007/input/input33
[ 1856.061121] hid-multitouch 0003:0416:C168.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [TSTP MTouch] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
```

Comment: You mentioned the 4.9 kernel. It is five years old, an eternity! First, try with a recent kernel!

Comment: I did, I wrote I tried with mainline too! Actually I have tried with a couple of versions, including 5.10, 5.15... No luck, same problem!

Comment: have you tried plugging the touch panel into a Windows PC or a Mac?

Comment: Yes I did and it works just fine on Windows (same workstation, it works on both linux and Windows)! I don't have a Mac to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning iommu off in the bios, then try adding `iommu=soft` in your kernel parameters.

Source=https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5738917.html

Comment: I'm not aware of any bios interface for the khadas to be honest! I'm trying to figure out what should I do exactly after running `make kernel-config` to add iommu=soft as a kernel parameter properly!

Comment: If you're using grub, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `iommu=soft` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. I might have confused "kernel paramater" and "boot parameter"

Comment: I placed that into the `Default kernel command string` within the ui of `make kernel-config`. Flashed the kernel and the result is the same unfortunately.